# Construction of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let $ m \in \mathbb{N}$ be fixed and $q=p^n$ (a variable prime power) for $n \in \mathbb{N}$  and $p$ prime. We define 
$$c_m=|\left\lbrace f \in \mathbb{F}_q[X]; f \ \text{irreducible, monic, deg}(f)=m \right\rbrace|. $$

I want to prove the following statements:

(A) $q$ relatively prime to $m$ $\Longrightarrow$ $q \mid c_m$

(B) $\exists$ a monic polynomial $C_m \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ with $\text{deg}(C_m)=m$ so that $c_m=\frac{C_m(q)}{m}$ for all $q$.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

**A:** We can let the additive group of the field $\Bbb{F}_q$ act on the set of monic irreducible polynomials of degree $m$ as follows. Let $f(x)$, a monic irreducible of degree $m$, and $\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_q$ be arbitrary. Then prove that $f(x+\alpha)$ is also a monic irreducible, and that this defines a group action. The upshot is to prove that if an irreducible monic has a non-trivial stabilizer, then necessarily $\gcd(m,q)\ge p$. Here you can use the fact that all the element of the field have additive order $p$.

**B:** It looks like you already solved this one.

Comment: As you have the formula for the number of monics of a given degree at hand, an admittedly easier way to do part A is to observe that when $\gcd(q,m)=1$ an integer $c$ is divisible by $q$ if and only $mc$ is divisible by $q$ :-)

Comment: If you had that formula in advance, then this exercise is, indeed, a bit strange. Anyway, the point of the hint is that can partition the degree $m$ irreducible polynomials into classes such that polynomials $f(x+\alpha),\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_q$ form one class. Either all the polynomials in such a class are irreducible or none are. Furthermore, when $\gcd(q,m)=1$ all such classes have exactly $q$ distinct polynomials. Therefore $c_m=q\times$ the number of such classes of irreducible polynomials, i.e. a multiple of $q$.